# Correct definition of an AC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

What is the correct definition for an AC circuit?  I have seen tutorial information that seems to say that an AC circuit is a closed loop of wire analogous to a DC circuit, except that the power source is AC and the current keeps reversing direction.  However, I have also seen tutorial information that says that dipole radio antennas are AC circuits (whether transmitting or receiving), which use a straight piece of wire (not a closed loop).  Can you have one kind of AC circuit using a closed loop of wire and another kind of AC circuit that uses a straight piece of wire?  Thank you.

Comment: In a radio transmitter/receiver circuit, you cannot assume the voltage on a wire being all the same everywhere. That's the big difference. In a straight antenna, you have different voltages in the middle and at the ends and the same time. This is why a current is flowing.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you have one kind of AC circuit using a closed loop of wire and
>   another kind of AC circuit that uses a straight piece of wire?

When you apply a signal to a wire whose length is long compared to the wavelength of the signal you get reflections from the far end if it is not terminated correctly: -

[image]

Imagine the red waveform is a sinewave travelling from left to right. The green line represents that waveform being reflected from an open circuit at the right. The blue is the sum of those two signals i.e. if you connected an oscilloscope to any point on the wire you would see the voltage represented by the blue waveform.

All of the above usually happens at high frequencies because it takes time for electricity to travel the length of the wire and several oscillations may have occured before the intial oscillation has reached the end and is reflected.

The same sort of thing happens when a cable changes from one type to another: -

[image]

A pulse signal enters from the left and hits a discontinuity near the middle - some energy is returned to the sending and and some energy continues.

> I have also seen tutorial information that says that dipole radio
>   antennas are AC circuits (whether transmitting or receiving), which
>   use a straight piece of wire (not a closed loop)

This happens in a dipole antenna along the length of the two wires from where the signal enters the antenna. There isn't an obvious discontinuity - it's gradual over the length of the wire in the antenna. What this does is raise the impedance of the signal from (say) 70 ohms (dipole input impedance) to a significantly higher impedance: -

[image]

You should be able to see that the moving red pattern represents the voltage along the wire - notice how at the ends of the wire that peak voltage is very much bigger than the voltage delivered by the driving source - i.e. there is voltage magnification and impedance transformation.

It's a really big subject so don't be surprised if it isn't that intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

'A piece of wire', as beloved by question setters and SPICE simulations connects different part of a single electrical node, and has uniform voltage and constant current along it (think light inextensible string, or spherical cow in a vacuum).

'An antenna' does not behave like a 'piece of wire', even though it can be made from wire. It's a transmission line. If you want to think of what it's doing, imagine it made up of a number of series inductors, with capacitors to ground every so often. The capacitors complete the circuit. The voltage and current are not uniform along the line.

In either complete circuit, if a DC source is used, current flows steadily. If an AC source is used, the the current keeps reversing direction.

Depending on the length of wire, and the frequency of the AC, real wires tend to behave more like pieces of wire (short, low frequency), or antennae/transmission lines (long, high frequency). At mains frequencies, all wires are short, unless you string them from one side of a continent to the other.